# Laravel Minio Temporary URL

Tags: laravel, minio, laravel-sail

I'm looking for a hacky way to create temporary URLs with Minio

I see on the Laravel docs it says: `Generating temporary storage URLs via the temporaryUrl method is not supported when using MinIO.`

However from some digging I noticed that I can upload images successfully using:

`AWS_ENDPOINT=http://minio:9000`

I can't view them because the temporary url is on `http://minio:9000/xxx`

If I change the AWS endpoint to

`AWS_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:9000`

The temporary url is on `http://localhost:9000/xxx`, the signature is validated and the file can be viewed.

The issue exists in this call to make the command. The `$command` needs to have the host changed but I don't know if I can do that by just passing in an option.

```
        $command = $this->client->getCommand('GetObject', array_merge([
            'Bucket' => $this->config['bucket'],
            'Key' => $this->prefixer->prefixPath($path),
        ], $options));
```

There is also the option to just change the `baseUrl` by providing a `temporary_url` in the filesystem config. however, because the URL has changed the signature is invalid.

Is there a way I can update the S3Client to use a different host either by passing an option to the getCommand function or by passing a new S3Client to the AWS adapter to use the correct host?

Answer (score 1):

A very hacky solution I've found is to re-create the AwsS3Adatapter:

```
      if (is_development()) {
        $manager = app()->make(FilesystemManager::class);
        $adapter = $manager->createS3Driver([
          ...config("filesystems.disks.s3_private"),
          "endpoint" => "http://localhost:9000",
        ]);

        return $adapter->temporaryUrl(
          $this->getPathRelativeToRoot(),
          now()->addMinutes(30)
        );
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i was hoping for a non hacky way